# How can i detect Adobe AIR version through javascript?

Tags: javascript, air

I want to detect the adobe AIR version through javascript..how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this variable `NativeApplication.nativeApplication.runtimeVersion` in javascript you can use `air.NativeApplication.nativeApplication.runtimeVersion` after including air alias file

I don't know how are you going to use it, but it is better to check for supported features rather than checking for version.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=runtime_os_info_1.html